# I don't understand why my get request is returning not a NaN?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, xmlhttprequest

### I'm building a store and am having trouble connecting to my remote server. Specifically, I'm have trouble getting my Products page to specific Product Detail page. I am trying to follow along with Angular's tutorial page. Currently, I'm at an impasse. Here is the error message that I get from my console when I click on a specific link:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

my-json-server.typicode.com/wlawlerpro/db/products/NaN:1

---

The get request which triggers this issue is the following.

```js
getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
  const url = `${this.productsURL}/${id}`; 
  return this.http.get<Product>(url)
  
}
```

```
 The following is the service page for my store:
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product, productss, } from './product'
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, } from 'rxjs';

import{ catchError, map, shareReplay, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ObserveOnSubscriber } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/observeOn';
import { MapOperator } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
//import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {
  private productsURL = 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/wlawlerpro/db/products'; 
  private productsURL2 = 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/wlawlerpro/db'
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
constructor(
  private http: HttpClient
) {}

private total = 0; 
private totalSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.total); 
public totalOberservable = this.totalSubject$.asObservable(); 
private  items : Product[] = []; 

private itemList$ = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>(this.items); 
public itemsObservable1 = this.itemList$.asObservable();


  
  

  addToCart(item: Product): void {
    this.items.push(item);
    this.itemList$.next(this.items); 
    this.total = this.calculateTotal(); 
    this.totalSubject$.next(this.total); 
    
    
  }
  
  removeFromCart(index: number){
    this.items.splice(index,1)
    this.total = this.calculateTotal(); 
    this.totalSubject$.next(this.total)

  }
  
  getItems() {
    return this.itemList$.asObservable(); 
  }
/*
getItems(): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.get<items>(this.catalogURL)

}
*/ 
  clearCart() {
    this.items = []; 
    return this.items;
  }
  

  private calculateTotal(): number {
    let total = 0; 
    this.items.forEach(
      (item: { price: number}) =>
      (total += item.price * 1)
    ); 
    return total; 
  }
 //Product List 
 
 getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsURL)
  .pipe(
    tap(), 
  );
 }

getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
  const url = `${this.productsURL}/${id}`; 
  return this.http.get<Product>(url)
  
}



}
```

I can hard code a number to the end of the get request and everything will work but only to the product id of the number I just hard coded. This is not what I'm trying to do. I want the id to link the whatever product id number belongs to the link that is clicked
Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Can you console.log value from ` const url = `${this.productsURL}/${id}`; `

Comment: I think the `NaN:1` in your error-message indicates that the `id` you pass to `getProduct()` is not a valid number.

Comment: kellermat is right. But the error does not seen to be in the code fragments you posted. It's probably in the component or in the template. Where do you _call_ `cartService.getProduct(id)`?

Comment: I imagine you get the "id" in a component you subscribe to activatedRouter.paramMap.pipe(...). See that the "params" is a string, so you need make somelike`const id=Number(params.get('id'));`or `const id=+params.get('id')` -the "+" try to convert, e.g. the string `"3"` to `3`

Comment: @O.Meekoh    The console.log value from const is: 
https://my-json-server.typicode.com/wlawlerpro/db/products/NaN

Comment: @lentschi I make the call on my product details component. 
The call is as follows :
 getProduct(): void {
  const id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!, 10); 
  this.cartService.getProduct(id)
  .subscribe(product => this.product = product);
  }

Comment: Well that route will only work, if the `id` parameter is in fact set in the URL. Is it? (I guess not, which is probably why the conversion produces `NaN`).
I think nobody is going to be able to help you unless you provide more details - E.g. by sharing your source through StackBlitz: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/getting-started-v0/stackblitz.html <- Fork this, make your changes - and if the error still occurs, post the fork URL here.